# Importing & using HoltWinters from hardPredictions

Tags: python, import, model, time-series

I'm stuck on importing a module from hardPredictions. I can find documentation on [installing the library](https://pypi.org/project/hardPredictions/)and using the module [module](https://hardpredictions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HoltWinters.html), but not how to import the module.

I've tried the following:

```
from hardPredictions import HoltWinters
model = HoltWinters()
```

This gives me an error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-72e6928695cf> in <module>
----> 1 model = HoltWinters()

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This works, but then I can't pass my ts to the model:

```
from hardPredictions import HoltWinters
model = HoltWinters
model.fit(ts)
```

gives an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-f40ff401465a> in <module>
      1 model = HoltWinters
----> 2 model.fit(ts)
```

AttributeError: module 'hardPredictions.HoltWinters' has no attribute 'fit'

I've also tried running help() and dir() on HoltWinters, but think the main thing is I'm lacking the skill to ask the *library* how to import a model. Your advice is much appreciated!